# Create an array based on same Id in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

This an example request object.

```
"stories": [
{
  "ID": "1",
  "TRADER_ID": "38",
  "IMAGE": ""
},
{
  "ID": "2",
  "TRADER_ID": "38",
  "IMAGE": ""
},
{
  "ID": "3",
  "TRADER_ID": "40",
  "IMAGE": ""
},
{
  "ID": "4",
  "TRADER_ID": "40",
  "IMAGE": ""
},]
```

like this i will be having list of story, I want create an array based on same TRADER_ID. because i need to add an image slide slider, for unique Traader Id i can get the image url

Comment: please add the wanted result **and** what you have tried. please have a look here, too: [mcve]

Comment: What does "based on same TRADER_ID" mean? You can give an example?

Comment: No idea on this

Comment: What is the output that you expect to get

Comment: What is the result you want?

Comment: This question does not show any research effort...

Comment: A combination of `array.map`, `array.filter` or `array.reduce` is what you want for manipulating arrays. However without knowing what the desired output is there's not much we can do without making assumptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is madness I know, but works. If anyone is able to simplify it, please do it :P

**OP wrote**: "*i need output like ["38", "38"] ["40", "40"]*"

```js
var stories = [{
  "ID": "1",
  "TRADER_ID": "38"
}, {
  "ID": "2",
  "TRADER_ID": "38"
}, {
  "ID": "3",
  "TRADER_ID": "40"
}, {
  "ID": "4",
  "TRADER_ID": "40"
}];

(function change(array) {
    var ids = [];
    stories.forEach(v => ids.push(v.TRADER_ID));
    var sortedArr = [...new Set(Array.from(ids))];
    var newOne = [];
    var times = 0;
    var obj = {};
    var result = [];
    var cb = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < sortedArr.length; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < stories.length; j++) {
        if (stories[j].TRADER_ID == sortedArr[i]) {
          times++;
        }
      }
      obj.prop = sortedArr[i];
      obj.times = times;
      newOne.push(obj);
      obj = {};
      times = 0;
    }

    for (var k = 0; k < newOne.length; k++) {
      for (var l = 0; l < newOne[k].times; l++) {
        cb.push(newOne[k].prop);
      }
      result.push(cb);
      cb = [];
    }
    console.log(result);
  
})(stories);
```

Comment: You could achieve similar results using `reduce` and `map`. [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rqmxhmr4/1/)

Comment: @ste2425 Amazing. Thank you

Comment: @KingUser No problem, was good fun. You could change the `reduce` to use a `map` as its base. then you could group on anything as a value, arrays, functions other objects. However `map` key equality check is by reference so that may not be of much use.

Comment: @ste2425 Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ID as the index of array and the TRADER_ID as number and make a sort or find the element by numbres (TRADER_ID)